# doctrine manager tries to update my User entity even without me making any modifications to it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

I have a controller method where I'm making a insert method for my entity `Order`, it has a relation with the `User` entity, a user can have many orders, now when I'm creating my order and set a user to it, doctrine tries to update the user when I did no modifications to it, I want to know what I'm doing wrong
my Controller method

```
    #[Route('/new', name: 'new', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function order(
        Request $request,
        ServiceRepository $serviceRepository,
        EntityManagerInterface $manager
    ): JsonResponse
    {
        $data = json_decode(json: $request->getContent());

        //get service
        if (!property_exists($data, 'service'))
            return $this->json(['status' => false, 'message' => 'service is required']);
        $service = $serviceRepository->find($data->service);

        $order = new Order();

        $order->setUser($this->getUser());
                $order->setCreatedAt(new \DateTimeImmutable());
        $order->setTotal(0);
        $order->setStatus(Order::STATUS_OPEN);
        $order->setService($service);

        $manager->persist($order);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->json(['status' => true]);
    }
```

my User entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity('email', message: 'This Email Is Taken')]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank, Assert\Email]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var ?string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $password_token = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $password_time = null;


    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: Order::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $total;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->total = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        unset($this->password, $this->roles, $this->access_token, $this->refresh_token, $this->updated_at);
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

   /**
    * @return string|null
    */
   public function getPasswordToken(): ?string
   {
       return $this->password_token;
   }

   /**
    * @param string|null $password_token
    */
   public function setPasswordToken(?string $password_token): void
   {
       $this->password_token = $password_token;
   }

   /**
    * @return \DateTimeImmutable|null
    */
   public function getPasswordTime(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
   {
       return $this->password_time;
   }

   /**
    * @param \DateTimeImmutable|null $password_time
    */
   public function setPasswordTime(?\DateTimeImmutable $password_time): void
   {
       $this->password_time = $password_time;
   }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Order>
     */
    public function getTotal(): Collection
    {
        return $this->total;
    }

    public function addTotal(Order $total): self
    {
        if (!$this->total->contains($total)) {
            $this->total->add($total);
            $total->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTotal(Order $total): self
    {
        if ($this->total->removeElement($total)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($total->getUser() === $this) {
                $total->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and my Order Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\OrderRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: OrderRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`order`')]
class Order
{
   public const STATUS_OPEN = 'open';
   public const STATUS_AWAITING_PAYMENT  = 'awaiting_payment';
   public const STATUS_PAYMENT_VALIDATED = 'payment_validated';
   public const STATUS_PAYMENT_CANCELLED = 'payment_cancelled';
   public const STATUS_COMPLETED = 'completed';

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'total')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $user = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?float $total = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $status = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'parent', targetEntity: OrderItem::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $activity;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'orders')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Service $service = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->activity = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotal(): ?float
    {
        return $this->total;
    }

    public function setTotal(float $total): self
    {
        $this->total = $total;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, OrderItem>
     */
    public function getActivity(): Collection
    {
        return $this->activity;
    }

    public function addActivity(OrderItem $activity): self
    {
        if (!$this->activity->contains($activity)) {
            $this->activity->add($activity);
            $activity->setParent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeActivity(OrderItem $activity): self
    {
        if ($this->activity->removeElement($activity)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($activity->getParent() === $this) {
                $activity->setParent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getService(): ?Service
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

    public function setService(?Service $service): self
    {
        $this->service = $service;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

so I tried to save the order, after that I save order items with the order id is the order saved above except it fails and gives me the contstrain error `An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'roles' cannot be null`
after debuging I found that doctrine is tryig to update my user here, but I made 0 modifications to the user so why would it be updated?

Comment: Still having trouble with this?  It's possible the user is not being properly loaded by your security system.  Make another controller action and do nothing but `$this->getUser(); $em->flush();` to see if that is the problem.

Comment: @Cerad yes, that's exactly the problem, I did exactly as you said, and I got the problem again

Comment: So assuming 'POST /new' required an authenticated user then you need to figure out why the User entity is not being properly loaded.  If you have a custom UserProvider class then that is the obvious place to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so guys, I forgot to answer this after finding the answer, as you can see in my User entity I have the method eraseCredentials

```
/**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        unset($this->password, $this->roles, $this->access_token, $this->refresh_token, $this->updated_at);
    }
```

I had a misunderstanding that I call this method before returning the user in an API request but it get called also before flushing, so care with that